LINUX OS - Window resizing keymaps not working
This question follows this one.
I set some custom keymaps to ease window resizing, such as nmap <A-j> <C-w>-.
However, they do not seem to work in any window. But, if I play the command manually, it works. What am I getting wrong?
NOTE: <C-j>, <C-k> are already taken to navigate. Here I want to resize, hence the different special key "Alt".

On some terminal the mapping to <Alt> could be problematic. What if you have: nnoremap <A-j> :echom 'alt-j'<Cr> and hit <Alt-j>. Do you have alt-j in the messages (i.e.: in the result of the :messages command)?

@VivianDeSmedt no, I don't have any message printed..

It probably means you have to do something to catch the  key. Could you tell us: what is the version of Vim you are using? What is your OS (Linux, maxOS, Windows)? What os the terminal you are using (Tmux, Kitty, cmd, ...)?

@VivianDeSmedt vim version: VIM - Vi IMproved 8.2 (2019 Dec 12, compiled May 03 2024 02:37:51) Included patches: 1-579, 1969, 580-1848, 4975, 5016, 5023, 5072, 2068, 1849-1854, 1857, 1855-1857, 1331, 1858, 1858-1859, 1873, 1860-1969, 1992, 1970-1992, 2010, 1993-2068, 2106, 2069-2106, 2108, 2107-2109, 2109-3995, 4563, 4646, 4774, 4895, 4899, 4901, 4919, 213, 1840, 1846-1847, 2110-2112, 2121, OS LInux Ubuntu 22.04.1, using its built-in terminal.

Maybe this answer could help you.
